# SCardEstablishContext: Service not available

Tags: linux, backtrack, smartcard, libusb

I installed the following packages:

- libusb-dev
- libusb++-0.1-4c2
- libccid
- pcscd
- libpcsclite1
- libpcsclite-dev
- List item
- libpcsc-perl
- pcsc-tools

But when I send the pcsc_scan command I received the below output :

```
root@bt:/# pcsc_scan
PC/SC device scanner
V 1.4.16 (c) 2001-2009, Ludovic Rousseau <ludovic.rousseau@free.fr>
Compiled with PC/SC lite version: 1.5.3
SCardEstablishContext: Service not available.
root@bt:/#
```

Why?

**Note:** I use BackTrack5

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It look like your pcscd is not running (service pcscd start).

Comment: I executed this `sudo service pcscd start` command on Mint LMDE. LED on smart card reader start to flash, but when I type again `sudo pcsc_scan` it gives me: `PC/SC device scanner
V 1.4.27 (c) 2001-2011, Ludovic Rousseau <ludovic.rousseau@free.fr>
Compiled with PC/SC lite version: 1.8.17
SCardEstablishContext: Service not available.`

Comment: systemctl enable pcscd
systemctl start pcscd

Answer (score 6):

Quick `strace pcsc_scan` reveals that it tries to open a non-existing file `/var/run/pcscd/pcscd.comm`:

```
stat("/var/run/pcscd/pcscd.comm", 0x7fff315e9dc0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
....
SCardEstablishContext: Service not available.
...
exit_group(-1)                          = ?
+++ exited with 255 +++
```

And indeed it does not exist:

```
$ ls /var/run/pcscd/pcscd.comm
ls: cannot access '/var/run/pcscd/pcscd.comm': No such file or directory
```

This is because there are two parts of pcscd: `pcscd.service` and `pcscd.socket`, where [the latter is responsible for that missing file](https://ludovicrousseau.blogspot.com/2011/11/pcscd-auto-start-using-systemd.html). Therefore, the proper solution will be:

```
sudo systemctl restart pcscd.socket
```

Demo:

```bsh
$ ls /var/run/pcscd/pcscd.comm
ls: cannot access '/var/run/pcscd/pcscd.comm': No such file or directory
$ sudo systemctl restart pcscd.socket
$ ls /var/run/pcscd/pcscd.comm
/var/run/pcscd/pcscd.comm
```

Now you can properly enjoy your `pcsc_scan`.